# Parse java console output with awk

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to use awk to parse an output generated by a java application, but it isn't working. It seems that the command after the pipe isn't able to get/see the data throwed by the java app.

I'm executing the following command (with the return generated by the command):

```
[root@localhost]# java -jar jmxclient.jar usr:pass host:port java.lang:type=Threading ThreadCount
06/11/2010 15:46:37 -0300 org.archive.jmx.Client ThreadCount: 103
```

What I need it's only the last part of the string. So I'm tryng to use awk (with pipe at the end of the line `|awk -F ':' '{print $4}'`:

```
[root@localhost]# java -jar jmxclient.jar usr:pass host:port java.lang:type=Threading ThreadCount|awk -F ':' '{print $4}'
```

But the output isn't being parsed. It throws the entire string: `06/11/2010 15:46:37 -0300 org.archive.jmx.Client ThreadCount: 103`

I also tryed to use `|cut -f4 -d":"` with the same result: the string isn't parsed.

So my question is, how do I parse the output in order to get just the number at the end of the string?

TIA,

Bob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said, it's probably going to stderr.  As well, there's an awk trick that will make your life easier: `$NF`, which is the last field.  Thus, I would do something like this:

```
java -jar jmxclient.jar usr:pass host:port java.lang:type=Threading ThreadCount 2>&1 | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 3):

The log is probably being output to stderr.

[Instructions for bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047)

Comment: Thanks. That was the case. But simply using 2>$1 was generating an ambiguous redirect error. Using Bill Weiss awk trick solved it.

Comment: `2>$1` won't work, but `2>&1` will.  I'm just adding on to that with a bit of Awk-fu.